# How to listen to keypress event in a background task

Tags: c#, .net, raspberry-pi, background-process, windowsiot

I have a barcode scanner that will be recognized as a keyboard by Windows (IoT) and I like to write a `IBackgroundTask` that fires an event if a new barcode was scanned. How can I listen to the keypress event of the keyboard in a background task on Windows IoT?

Comment: So you want to trigger your background task by key press?

Comment: No the background task is already running and I like to get an event if a key is pressed.

Comment: Why would you want to register the event in your background task?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the following discussion (describes using a keyboard hook in c# in windows mobile 6.5): http://www.intermec.com/site/realtime/SingleArticleList.aspx?id=17093
Unfortunately there is not a message pump in Windows 10 IoT Core (as there is no gui), so this sample won't work for you.
A much better solution would be to utilize an serial port barcode scanner, setup a thread to listen to the serial port and then do your processing. An example of listening to the serial port is here: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/win10/samples/serialsample
Any serial port scanner will do (such as the Motorola Symbol LS2208)

Comment: Please avoid to refer to external sources without including in your answer a summary of the main points.